# Problema al llenar OPTION/COMBOBOX/DROPDOWNLIST CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer llenar un Combobox/dropdownList en CakePHP

lo lleno asi:

```
    public function obtComunas()
{
    $Comuna = $this->ManComuna->find()->select(['codigo_comuna', 'descripcion'])->toArray();
    return $Comuna;
}
```

y en la vista lo muestro así:

```
            echo $this->Form->input('codigo_comuna',  
                                array(
                                'type'    => 'select',
                                'options' => $Comunas,
                                'empty'   => false
                                ));
```

El problema es que no se como indicar al combo cual es el valor y cual es el texto, por ende se me ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano muchas gracias a cualquier comentario.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por la ayuda, pero encontré una solución. No se si será lo mas optimo ni lo correcto, pero a mi me funcionó.

En la consulta le agregué un foreach y llené otro arreglo con los valores.

```
    public function obtComunas()
{
    $Comuna = $this->ManComuna->find()->select(['codigo_comuna', 'descripcion']);
    $st=array();
    foreach ($Comuna as $row) {
        $st[$row['codigo_comuna']] = $row['descripcion'];
    }
    return $st;
}
```

La vista la dejé tal cual.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para un select list necesitas usar un find list
muestro ejemplo de conditions, pueden poner la condicion que quiere que cumpla su consulta y recuerden que el recursive indica el nivel de profundiad al que queremos ingresar en las relaciones.

**controller**

```
$this->loadModel('clase_producto');

$productos = $this->clase_producto->find('list', array('conditions' => 
array('clase_producto.idel' => 0), 'recursive' => 0));

$this->set(compact('productos'));
```

**view**

```
$form->input('producto_id',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$productos));
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería con `find list` y definiendo `keyPath` y `valuePath`

**TuControlador/obtComunas**

```
public function obtComunas()
{
    $comunas = $this->ManComuna->find('list', ['keyPath' => 'codigo_comuna','valuePath' => 'descripcion']);

    $this->set(compact('comunas'));
}
```

**Vista**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('codigo_comuna',['type' => 'select', 'options' => $comunas, 'empty' => false]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuándo estés realizando este tipo de consultas, no hay que hacer nada de lo anterior basta con que en el modelo de la tabla "padre" cambies la propiedad del campo que deseas mostrar, en lugar del id.

En este caso en el modelo "ProductosTable.php" dentro del método `initialize`:
    `$this->setDisplayField('descripcion');`

Recuerda que los nombres de las tablas y campos de tu bd deben cumplir con las "[Naming Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/es/intro/conventions.html#convenciones-de-modelo-y-base-de-datos)" de cakephp.