# Mostrar nombre en vez de la id cakephp list

Tags: php, lista, cakephp

Estoy utilizando cakephp y en la funcion add() me devuelve un listado de los Tipos de centros y en ese listado estan las id , me gustaría que mostrase otro campo diferente. 
Este es el código que viene.

```
$tipoCentros = $this->Usuarios->TipoCentros->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
```

Y esto es lo que he intentado pero me devuelve valores vacios

```
 $tipoCentros = $this->Usuarios->TipoCentros->find('list', 
 ['fields'=>'TipoCentros.descripcion','limit' => 200]);
```

Y en mi add.ctp tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 echo $this->Form->control('tipo_centro_id', ['options' => $tipoCentros]);
```

Comment: Por favor revisa esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40194/problema-al-llenar-option-combobox-dropdownlist-cakephp/339363#339363)

Answer (score 2):

Vale ya encontré mi solución la dejo por aquí por si alguien tenia la misma duda que yo.

```
$tipoCentros = $this->Usuarios->TipoCentros->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'descripcion',
        'limit' => 200]);
```